# My UITableView crashes when I add a gradient background?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, swift-playground

I have a UITableView under a UIViewController with a custom cell. The text for the UILabel in each cell is held in an array of strings. I’m coding in Swift Playgrounds, and when I run the Playground with an empty array it works fine (there aren’t an cells, of course, but the playground does run). When I populate the array, I get the error “there as a problem running this page... check your code...”. When I step through the code, it gets stuck at the line:

```
view.addSubview(gradientView)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Array that holds menu items
    var menuItems = ["option 1","option 2","option 3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Add a gradient background

        // Set height, width to view height, width
        var gradientView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        let gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame.size = gradientView.frame.size

        // Set colors
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 94/255, blue: 172/255, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 121/255, green: 73/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]

        // Skew gradient (diagonally)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) 
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)

        // Rasterize to improve performance
        gradientLayer.shouldRasterize = true

        //Add gradient
        gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        view.addSubview(gradientView)

        // Reguster custom cell
        tableView.register(MenuItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_1")

        // Turn off seperators
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        // Set header height
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 75
    }

    // Custom header
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{
        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 75))
        customView.backgroundColor = .clear //UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("", for: .normal)

        button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style:
            UIBlurEffect.Style.light))
        blur.frame = button.bounds
        blur.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //This allows touches to forward to the button.
        button.insertSubview(blur, at: 0)

        customView.addSubview(button)
        return customView
    }


    @objc func updateView(){

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1", for: indexPath) as! MenuItemCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        //cell.messageLabel.text = textMessages[indexPath.row]

        cell.bubbleBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        return cell

    }

}



class MenuItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    let optionLabel = UILabel()
    let bubbleBackgroundView = UIView()




    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        bubbleBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        bubbleBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(bubbleBackgroundView)

        addSubview(optionLabel)

        optionLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        optionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // lets set up some constraints for our label
        let constraints = [optionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 32),
                           optionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 32),
                           optionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
                           optionLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),

                           bubbleBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionLabel.topAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
                           bubbleBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: optionLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
        ]





        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: [It is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KozyU.png). What is the issue?

Comment: When I add elements to the menuItems array, it does not work.